# Google Chrome SELECT a certifcate

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have installed ssl on node js server which seems working fine.

Now few user are complaining about they are getting popup like this one

[image]

What does it mean ?

Does SSL doesn't configured properly.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `requestCert: true` in your `https.createServer()` config object?

Comment: Yes. the value is set to true

Answer (score 2):

When you set `requestCert: true` in your `https.createServer()` config object, the server requests a certificate from the client for the purpose of authentication before the connection is allowed.

How this is handled by the client can vary, but as you can see some browsers may present the user with a list of certificates installed on the system when the server requests this kind of authentication.

If you are not using this TLS-level mechanism for authentication, then either set `requestCert: false` or leave the option out completely (it defaults to `false`) in your server config object.

Comment: Could you please explain TLS-level mechanism

Comment: And how can i regenerate issue on my window machine for testing. i am not  able to regenerate issue